# Azure is ignoring Scheduling settings for WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I deployed a WebJob the suggested way using Visual Studio, right-click onto the console project, selecting "Publish as Azure Webjob" and going through the settings. 
I selected a scheduled plan what caused the file "`webjob-publish-settings.json`" to be created in the Properties-Folder with the following content:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "TestCredentials2",
  "startTime": "2016-04-05T01:00:00+01:00",
  "endTime": "2016-04-12T00:00:00+01:00",
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Minute",
  "interval": 3,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

While the deployment worked, the webjob is in the state "On Demand". The Webjob is run **once** when I start it manually from within the Azure Portal but does not restart ever automatically.

I also tried to add a "`settings.job`" to the root of my project (with the setting "Copy if newer"):

`{ "schedule": "0 /5 * * * *"` }

Still no difference in the behaviour, but also no error message.

Comment: The suggested approach is to use CRON expressions (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON). You questions asks about both at the same time, so it is likely to cause confusion between the two (it's really questions). If you have troubles getting the CRON expression to work, I suggest asking a question that focuses on that  exclusively.

Comment: I added the second (settings.job) just because the first approach did not work in the hope that might work.

Comment: Understood, but that ends up sort of asking two questions since they work widely differently.

Comment: I solved this by using a contious webjob and using Threading.Timer. More a hack than a solution.

Comment: there is a timertrigger for webjob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218203/continuous-webjob-with-timer-trigger/36245328#36245328

Comment: I really think you should focus your question on trying to understand why CRON expression is not working for you. It is the correct solution and is supposed to work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It did work using the `settings.job` approach. The following things had to be done:

```
1. Create a settings.job with the content in the question
2. select Build Action "Content" for that file
3. Select "Copy if newer"
4. Delete the generated "Properties/webjob-publish-actions.json"
5. Re-Publish the Project, chose "On Demand" instead of a schedule plan
```

this creates a new webjob-publish-actions.json:

```
{
      "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
      "webJobName": "MyTimer",
      "startTime": null,
      "endTime": null,
      "jobRecurrenceFrequency": null,
      "interval": null,
      "runMode": "OnDemand"
    }
```

Done.