# Azure Web Job Timmer trigger exception

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to run a triggered azure web job using azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions)

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.UseTimers();

JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("CronJob"));
host.RunAndBlock();

public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cron job fired!");
}
```

But I'm getting this exception.

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host System.ObjectDisposedException
```

I've also tried downloding the sample projects from that gitbug repo, but even with those TimerTrigger examples I'm getting the same exception.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of the sdk are you using ?

Comment: Latest version. 1.0.1 I installed it through nuget without specifying a version so I assume it took the latest stable one (I reverted the code so that's why I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: Can you comment this line `host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("CronJob"));` ? You dont need it. Can you have a look at this answer and tell me if it working http://stackoverflow.com/a/34235136/4167200?

Comment: Yeah. It appears that was part of the problem, although I remember trying that. Changed some versions of nugets and it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("CronJob"));

Please pay attention that you should provide the `CronJob` function with a `TimerInfo` parameter. The `CronJob` function is invoked automatically by the `TimeTrigger` you defined. If you want to invoke the `CronJob` function before you call `host.RunAndBlock()`, you could refer to the following code:

```
host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("CronJob"),new { timerInfo = new TimerInfo(null, null) });
```

> But I'm getting this exception.Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host System.ObjectDisposedException

According to your description, I downloaded the example projects from the GitHub you mentioned and found the versions of related package are old. Please follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extensible-triggers-and-binders-with-azure-webjobs-sdk-1-1-0-alpha1/) to create an Azure WebJob project and install the latest version packages of [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/1.1.0-alpha1) and [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions/1.0.0-alpha1), then test your `TimeTrigger` function.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go at it now. I'll let you know if it works or not :)

Comment: Hmm .. it worked. I used  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs version 1.1.0 and Extensions 1.0.1.0 and I didn't call the method explicitly. Maybe I missed something yesterday, who knows. Thanks :)