# Cron expression for every week wednesday at 9:30 AM and 2nd of every month

Tags: azure, cron, job-scheduling, webjob

I'm using Azure WebJob to Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service. It's scheduled WebJob and I have following cron expression:

```
0 30 9 2 * 3
```

But it is not executing.

So my question is it possible to schedule this way. If not how to add 2 different schedules for a single webjob?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate schedules for Azure webjob functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376271/separate-schedules-for-azure-webjob-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Wednesday in every month is not equals to every 2nd day in month.

The format of CRON in wenjob is `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}`

You can set like this :`0 30 9 2 * *` or `0 30 9 * * 3`

Refer to [NCRONTAB expressions docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions).